# Printing DataGrid after cell manipulation

Tags: c#, datagrid, .net-4.5

I want to be able to print out a DataGrid that has been manipulated after some header column cell has been clicked. Say you clicked a "Name" column header to sort all of the names in the column and change the way the data is displayed, I've only found DataGrid printers that print out the first version of the was that the data was read in and not the sorted version. If anyone has any help or knows of any links that could help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: where are you printing it in ASP.NET WebApp or WinForm or WPF App?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad Sorry WinForm Visual Studio 2012

Comment: no problem at all... it's been sometime since I've seen Winforms. If I am not wrong , you might using the built in control for sorting that comes on the header . From what I recall , the sort simply changes on the UI side and your datasource remains same. You may need to do manual sorting , meant create a event on click and then change your datasource accordingly for the sort and bind.

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad How would I create an event on click if the columns are created once the data is read in from a database?

Comment: I think this is the event ColumnHeaderMouseClick , just create an event handler for this event and check if it's invoked when you click on the column header.

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad I tried and it's not working